# Applying Model-View-Controller to Tkinter/matplotlib Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, mvc, tkinter, matplotlib

I'm a novice programmer. I am preparing to refactor a large project of mine to follow a model/view/controller design pattern, with separate modules for each (and eventually separate modules for the view alone).

To learn how to do this right, I looked at examples from books and online, but there seemed to be no general agreement. Many of the simple examples only used one file for model, view, and controller combined, which I want to avoid. So, I created a small demo in order to learn how to structure such an app.

I would like feedback on whether I applied this pattern correctly, and have the separation of concerns between model, view and controller correct. For example, I have the controller responsible for holding default settings and initializing the view, and the controller script is to be run as the main program (and not the view, as in many demos). I tried to create each component with a minimal, documented API that would allow for parts to be "swapped out", e.g. adopt a different math model, or GUI such as PyQt, with minimal recoding.

Other feedback is welcome as well (e.g. tkinter code; use of docstrings; appropriateness of the question for Code Review), but the key bits are the Controller structure and the last three methods of View.

controller.py:

```
"""
The controller is to be executed as the main app in this MVC pattern demo. 

Assumes a tkinter view.

Contains:

* Controller    Class that handles data and requests to/from the model and 
                the view.
"""

import tkinter as tk
from view import View
import model


class Controller:
    """Class that instantiates a view, and passes data and requests to/from 
    the model and the view.

    Variables are passed between model, view, and controller in the format:

        values = {'base': b, 'exponent': e}

    where b and e are floats.

    The controller assumes the model accepts a values dict and returns an x, 
    y tuple of numpy arrays suitable for a matplotlib plot.

    The controller assumes the view offers the following methods:

    * set_values(values)        used to initialize the view
    * clear() and .plot(x, y)   for clearing the canvas and plotting the 
                                x, y data provided by the model, respectively.

    Controller provides the following method for external use by the view:

    * update_view    Recalculates plot data, and updates view's plot.
    """

    def __init__(self, root):
        """
        Argument:
            root: a tkinter.Tk() object, to be used by the view.
        """
        self.view = View(root, self)
        self.default_values = {'base': 1, 'exponent': 2}
        self.initialize_view()

    def initialize_view(self):
        """Initialize the view's entry widgets and plot canvas."""
        self.view.set_values(self.default_values)
        self.update_view(self.default_values)

    def update_view(self, values):
        """Request x, y plot data from the model, and update the view's plot 
        with the new data.

        Argument:
            values: dict in 'values' format
        """
        self.get_plot_data(values)
        self.update_view_plot()

    def get_plot_data(self, values):
        """Send the values to the model and store the plot data returned.

        Argument:
            values: dict in 'values' format
            """
        self.plot_data = model.powerplot(**values)

    def update_view_plot(self):
        """Call view's methods to clear and redraw its plot, 
        using Controller's copy of the plot data."""
        self.view.canvas.clear()
        self.view.canvas.plot(*self.plot_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Controller(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

model.py:

```
"""A test model consisting of a simple function.

Contains:

* powerplot    Function that provides (x, y) data suitable for matplotlib 
               plotting.
"""

import numpy as np


def powerplot(base, exponent):
    """
    Calculates data for plotting the function: y = (base * x) ** exponent,
    for x = 0...10.
    Arguments: base and exponent as floats
    Returns: two numpy arrays of x and y coordinates (length 800).
    """

    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 800)
    y = (x * base) ** exponent
    return x, y
```

view.py:

```
"""
Provides a View tkinter GUI suitable for plotting functions that use two 
numerical user inputs.

Contains:
* MPLgraph    A matplotlib backend tkinter widget used by View
* View    A tkinter GUI with two numerical entry boxes and a matplotlib canvas. 
"""

import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

mpl.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
                                               NavigationToolbar2TkAgg)
from tkinter import ttk


class MPLgraph(FigureCanvasTkAgg):
    """The canvas-like matplotlib object used by View.

    """
    def __init__(self, figure, parent=None, **options):
        """
        argument:
            figure: a matplotlib.figure.Figure object
        """
        FigureCanvasTkAgg.__init__(self, figure, parent, **options)
        self.figure = figure
        self.add = figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.show()
        self.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self, parent)
        self.toolbar.update()

    def plot(self, x, y):
        """Take two arrays for x and y coordinates and plot the data."""
        self.add.plot(x, y)
        self.figure.canvas.draw()  # DRAW IS CRITICAL TO REFRESH

    def clear(self):
        """Erase the plot."""
        self.add.clear()
        self.figure.canvas.draw()


class View(tk.Frame):
    """A tkinter GUI with two numerical entry boxes (labeled "base" and 
    "exponent"), and a matplotlib canvas. 

    View assumes the controller has an update_view method, that accepts 
    variables in the format:

        values = {'base': b, 'exponent': e}

    where b and e are floats, and returns an (x, y) tuple of numpy arrays.

    View provides the following methods for external use by the controller: 

    * set_values    used to initialize the view
    * clear    clears the MPLgraph plot
    * plot    plots data provided as x, y tuple of numpy arrays

    TODO: The view currently allows the controller to be called when widgets are 
    left empty, which results in a ValueError when the model is called. A 
    workaround such as filling empty entry widgets with 0. is required.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, **options):
        """Create the necessary widgets, and a dict self.values for 
        storing the state of the entry widgets in the format:
            {'base': b, 'exponent': e}
        where b and e are floats.

        Requires arguments:
            parent: parent widget
            controller: the object that provides the update_view method
        """
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, **options)
        self.pack()

        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller
        self.values = {}

        self.create_entries()
        self.create_bindings()
        self.create_canvas()

    def create_entries(self):
        """Add entry widgets and associated labels to View, and assign 
        StringVar objects to the entry widgets."""
        self.base_entry = self.add_entry('base')
        self.base = tk.StringVar()
        self.base_entry.config(textvariable=self.base)
        self.base_entry.focus_set()

        self.exponent_entry = self.add_entry('exponent')
        self.exponent = tk.StringVar()
        self.exponent_entry.config(textvariable=self.exponent)

    def add_entry(self, text):
        """Create a label with text=text, and an entry with numerical entry 
        validation; pack them; and return the entry object for future 
        reference.

        Argument:
            text:    string that is both the label text and the key for the 
                     self.values dict.
        Returns:
            entry:    The created ttk.Entry object
        """
        ttk.Label(self, text=text).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # check on each keypress for numerical entry
        entry = ttk.Entry(self, validate='key')
        entry['validatecommand'] = (self.register(self.is_number_or_empty),
                                    '%P')
        entry['invalidcommand'] = 'bell'  # beep if invalid keypress
        entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        return entry

    def is_number_or_empty(self, entry):
        """Test (e.g. on keypress) to see if entry status is acceptable (either 
        empty, or able to be converted to a float.)

        Argument:
            entry: string
        Returns:
            boolean
        """
        return self.is_number(entry) or self.is_empty(entry)

    @staticmethod
    def is_number(entry):
        """Test to see if entry value is a number.

         Argument:
            entry: string
        Returns:
            boolean
        """
        try:
            float(entry)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def is_empty(entry):
        if not entry:
            return True
        return False

    def create_bindings(self):
        """Bind events across all entry widgets"""
        self.bind_class('TEntry', '<FocusIn>',
                        lambda event: self.on_focus_in(event))
        self.bind_class('TEntry', '<Return>',
                        lambda event: self.on_value_entry(event))
        self.bind_class('TEntry', '<Tab>', lambda event: self.on_tab(event))
        self.bind_class('TEntry', '<FocusOut>',
                        lambda event: self.refresh(event))

    @staticmethod
    def on_focus_in(event):
        """Select the entire contents of entry widget upon focus, for easy 
        editing.
        """
        event.widget.selection_range(0, tk.END)

    def on_value_entry(self, event):
        """When a valid change to the entry is committed, request a view 
        refresh, and set focus on next entry widget."""
        self.refresh(event)
        self.set_next_focus(event.widget.tk_focusNext())

    def refresh(self):
        """Overwrite self.values and request a plot refresh, but only if an 
        entry's value is changed.
        """
        if self.entry_is_changed():
            self.update_values()
            self.controller.update_view(self.values)

    def entry_is_changed(self):
        """Compare current widget entries to the dictionary of previously 
        stored values.

        Returns: Boolean
        """
        if self.current_values() != self.values:
            return True
        return False

    def current_values(self):
        """Get current widget values and store them in a dictionary.

        Returns: a dict in self.values format
        """
        return {'base': float(self.base.get()),
                'exponent': float(self.exponent.get())}

    def update_values(self):
        """Overwrite the dictionary of previous entry values with that for 
        the current values."""
        self.values = self.current_values()

    def set_next_focus(self, NextWidget):
        """Starting with NextWidget, traverse the order of widgets until the 
        next Entry widget is found, then set focus to it. Used to ignore all 
        the matplotlib widgets.

        Argument:
            NextWidget: a tkinter widget
        """
        if type(NextWidget) is not ttk.Entry:
            self.set_next_focus(NextWidget.tk_focusNext())
        else:
            NextWidget.focus()

    def on_tab(self, event):
        """Wrapper of on_value_entry; required to override the Tab key's 
        default behavior."""
        self.on_value_entry(event)
        return 'break'

    def create_canvas(self):
        """Adds a MPLgraph widget to the bottom of View's parent."""
        self.figure = mpl.figure.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        self.canvas = MPLgraph(self.figure, self.parent)
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)

    # The three methods below provide the interface to the controller
    def set_values(self, values):
        """Used by the controller to initialize the view's entry values and 
        data.

        Argument:
            values: a dict in self.values format
        """
        self.base.set(values['base'])
        self.exponent.set(values['exponent'])
        self.values = values

    def clear(self):
        """ Erase the matplotlib canvas."""
        self.canvas.clear()

    def plot(self, x, y):
        """Plot the model's results to the matplotlib canvas.

        Arguments:
            x, y: numpy arrays of x and y coordinates
        """
        self.canvas.plot(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = View(root, controller=None)
    root.mainloop()
```